# UAE 96 hour transit visa problem

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, emirates

I and my wife are flying from Budapest to Mumbai with stopover in Dubai for 2 days. We are flying Emirates and we applied and got UAE 96 hour transit visa for both of us.

I booked two separate emirates tickets for me and wife since because of my credit card limits. We are of course traveling together.

In the emirates transit visa it is mentioned that "Accompanied by.." is None.

[image]

I believe this is because we booked two separate tickets, there were no provisions in the Emirates visa application to enter details accompanied by wife.

However i did attach supporting documents of marriage certificate in our transit visa applications. My wife's passport is endorsed my details as husband.

I am quite worried that this issue will cause problems when entering dubai when traveling with wife. Is this normal?

Comment: What type of problems do you expect? I see none?

Comment: when we go for passport control together, they may ask why my wife name is not present in the e-visa? They might think i am lying in my visa application traveling with wife. Is booking two separate tickets normal for husband and wife?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You show up at the immigration, explain that you booked two separate tickets, and get stamped-in as usual. There is nothing wrong with booking two separate tickets.

Relax and enjoy your stay.